# list comprehension Error " IndexError: list index out of range "

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to make list comprehension for the below code, the code works fine if comprehension not used.

This code is used to return the missing number in a sequence of numbers that have a constant difference between the consecutive terms of a given series of numbers.

```
def find_missing(sequence):
    difference = min(sequence[1] - sequence[0], sequence[-1] - sequence[-2])
    # for index in range(len(sequence)):
    #     if sequence[index] + difference != sequence[index+1]:
    #         return sequence[index] + difference
    # return [index for index in range(len(sequence))]
    return [sequence[index]+difference for index in range(len(sequence)) if sequence[index]+difference != sequence[index+1]]


print(find_missing([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]))  # ==5
print(find_missing([1, 3, 5, 9, 11]))  # == 7
print(find_missing([1, 3, 4]))  # == 2
```

I have an error message when using comprehension.
Error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: instead of `len(sequence)` use `len(sequence)-1`

Comment: could you give a not working example, which you saw the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an error because `index+1` in `sequence[index+1]` is one bigger than the array on the last iteration. Python generally discourages using indexes for loops — partially because it's so easy to create these kind of bugs.

If you want to compare adjacent elements, you can instead loop over `zip(sequence, sequence[1:])`. This will give you pairs that you can then compare — it's easier to read and you don't need to worry about index errors:

```
def find_missing(sequence):
    difference = min(sequence[1] - sequence[0], sequence[-1] - sequence[-2])

    return [ f + difference 
             for f, n in zip(sequence, sequence[1:]) 
             if  f + difference != n ]


print(find_missing([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]))  # == [5]
print(find_missing([1, 3, 5, 9, 11]))  # == [7]
print(find_missing([1, 3, 4]))  # == [2]
```

Comment: Thank you, Mark, for your simple explanation of the problem.